# Count number of strings in a list

Tags: python, string, list

```
list = ['abcd','xyz',12,13]
```

I want to count several strings in the above list. How can we do that?

I used the count method but it didn't work.

How to do that?

Comment: so you want to ccount the number of string elements? (ie here results in 2)

Comment: Your title does not match the body of your question. What output do you expect? What have you tried?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it needs clarification on what exactly the output should be.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a list comprehension:

```py
list = ['abcd','xyz',12,13]
num = len([x for x in list if isinstance(x, str)])
print(num)  # 2
```

Comment: Doesn't it say OP wants to count strings?

Comment: @user56700: "Number strings" in the title.

Comment: @BillLynch Ah ok, I'm not native English speaker, so that I didn't get, thanks. +1 from me then. I thought it should've said number of strings. Also in the body it says *I want to count several strings* :)

Comment: Sorry: I interpreted "number strings" as numbers.  Dyslexia.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah I'm not sure now what OP means.

Comment: @user56700: I'm a native english speaker and I'm not sure what the OP is asking for. If someone asked me for that, I'd assume they meant strings only containing numbers. Such as `"123"`.

Comment: @BillLynch Yeah, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count only strings in a list

```
list_one = ['abcd','xyz',12,13]
c = 0 
for i in list_one:
    if isinstance(i, str):
        c += 1
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's actually a list of string numbers like the title suggests, here are a couple of ways to do it

```
l = ['abcd', 'xyz' , '12' , '13']

# Using try
count = 0
for s in l:
    try:
        int(s)
        count += 1
    except ValueError:
        pass
print("numbers in list:", count)

count = 0
for s in l:
    if s.isdigit():
        count += 1
print("numbers in list:", count)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use type() to check string with list comprehension:

```
list = ['abcd','xyz',12,13]
print(len([x for x in list if type(x) is str]))
```